# Typescript return type of function from parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, typescript-typings

I would like to know how to do the following in typescript:

if I have this function:

```js
function getQueries(query) {
  return Object.keys(query).reduce((list, key) => {
    return { ...list, [key]: query[key].length > 3  }
  }, {})
}
```

in which I want to pass an object like this

```js
getQueries({ first: 'dsds', second: 'dsdsds', third: 'ds' })
```

and I want to type of that function to return exactly the same structure I'm passing, but instead with boolean as values.

```js
const queries = getQueries({ first: 'dsds', second: 'dsdsds', third: 'ds' })
queries.first // ts error -> Property 'first' does not exist on type '{}'
```

How can I approach this typing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for generics and mapped types:

```
function getQueries<T>(query: T): {[key in keyof T]: boolean} {
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me a jsfiddle/or_anything link with the right answer its still showing errors for me.

Answer (score 1):

My answer will be more for your specific case, I needed to little bit refactor current code to fullfill the type correctness. Consider fallowing code:

```
type BoolRecord<T extends Record<string, string>> = Record<keyof T, boolean> 
function getQueries<Q extends Record<string, string>>(query: Q): BoolRecord<Q> {
  return Object.keys(query).reduce((list, key) => {
    return { ...list, [key]: query[key as keyof Q].length > 3  }
  }, {} as BoolRecord<Q>)
}

const result = getQueries({ first: 'dsds', second: 'dsdsds', third: 'ds' });
// Record<"first" | "second" | "third", boolean>
```

My assumption was that function `getQueries` needs to get as an argument object with string values, as you inside are using `length` property (implementation checks `.length>3`). So the function argument type is `Record<string, string>`. Next step is to define the return type, and this is accomplished by `BoolRecord`, this type takes the original Record and creates the same but with bool fields as you wanted.

I used [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) utility type, but this can be achieved also by [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) (Record is actually mapped type).

Interesting part is the `BoolRecord` its definition says that for any Record give me Record with the same keys (done by `keyof T`) with bool as value type.